# Typescript: subclass/extend of Promise: does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript2.1

I'm trying to cancel my `async` method call in Typescript.

To do this, I have created a new Promise type, which inherits from `Promise`:

```js
class CancelablePromise<T> extends Promise<T>{

    private cancelMethod: () => void;
    constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void, cancelMethod: () => void) {
        super(executor);
        this.cancelMethod = cancelMethod;
    }

    //cancel the operation
    public cancel() {
        if (this.cancelMethod) {
            this.cancelMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to use it:

```js
async postFileAjax<T>(file: File): CancelablePromise<T> { ... }
```

I get the error:

> Error     Build:Type 'typeof CancelablePromise' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

If I using the type declaration and return the `CancelablePromise`, like this then it compiles:

```js
async postFileAjax<T>(file: File): Promise<T>  { 
     ...
     return CancelablePromise(...);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I see that in ES6 you could subclass the `Promise` (see [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351519/201303)), so I would expect it also in TypeScript.

Using Typescript 2.1 and targeting es5

Comment: You can't extend built-in types unless you target `es6` (or above)

Comment: if you have a reference for that, then that's the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Try this one: [Extending from Error doesn't work when emitting ES5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10166)

Comment: I split the compile and runtime error. Compile error has been solved, now runtime error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420175/typescript-subclass-extend-of-promise-gives-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-prom

Comment: Again, you cannot simply extend native types when targeting `es5`. Notice that when you target `es6` then the resulting code is different, it uses `es6` classes which makes the inheritance work.

Comment: What you should probably do is to implement `PromiseLike` instead of extending `Promise`

Comment: Then i am missing methods? Any way, I think this compilation issue has been solved (see my own answer).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message wasn't fully clear to me at first, but the signature of the constructor should be **completely the same** as the constructor of  `Promise`.

I've removed the `cancelMethod` from the constructor and will set it later. This works:

```
class CancelablePromise<T> extends Promise<T>{

    public cancelMethod: () => void;
    constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
        super(executor);

    }

    //cancel the operation
    public cancel() {
        if (this.cancelMethod) {
            this.cancelMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

and call:

```
async postFileAjax<T>(file: File): CancelablePromise <T> { 

    var promiseFunc = (resolve) => { resolve() };
    var promise = new CancelablePromise<T>(promiseFunc);
    promise.cancelMethod = () => { console.log("cancel!") };

    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy-pasting types from constructor parameters it's better to use utility type `ConstructorParameters` + `typeof`:

```js
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {

  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise<T>>) {
    super(...args);
  }

}
```

Adding argument is a bit tricky

```js
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {

  constructor(...args: [...ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise<T>>, () => void]) {
    const [executor, cancel] = args
    super(executor);

    this.cancel = cancel;
  }

}
```