# NodeJS: Cannot extend Promise object: No base constructor has the specified number of type arguments

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I am attempting to extend the `Promise` object with the following code:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            return executor(resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:
[image]

What does this error mean? How can I successfully extend `Promise`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    constructor(executor: (resolve: any, reject: any) => MyPromise<T>) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            return executor(resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? Can you please explain more?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure why this works. I am not well versed in TypeScript. I 'derived' the answer from information here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327229/typescript-subclass-extend-of-promise-does-not-refer-to-a-promise-compatible-c) and using a TypeScript sandbox. *blush*

Comment: You do not need to wrap the executor function in a lambda.
You can just pass it directly as it already fulfills the type constraints.

Try just: ```constructor(executor: (resolve: any, reject: any) => MyPromise<T>) { super(executor); }```

Comment: You don't need to define the constructor at all. All you need is the generic T for both MyPromise and Promise.