# Typescript: subclass/extend of Promise gives 'TypeError: undefined is not a promise' on run time

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript2.1

I'm trying to cancel my `async` method call in Typescript.

To do this, I have created a new Promise type, which inherits from `Promise`:

```js
class CancelablePromise<T> extends Promise<T>{

    public cancelMethod: () => void;
    constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
        super(executor);
        // Set the prototype explicitly.

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CancelablePromise.prototype);

    }

    //cancel the operation
    public cancel() {
        if (this.cancelMethod) {
            this.cancelMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

The first version was without the `Object.setPrototypeOf(..)`, but it was recommend [on the TypeScript GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work)

When I'm trying to use it, I get a run-time error (no compile errors):

```js
class Test{

    async postFileAjax<T>(file: File): CancelablePromise <T> { 

        var promiseFunc = (resolve) => { resolve() };
        var promise = new CancelablePromise<T>(promiseFunc);
        promise.cancelMethod = () => { console.log("cancel!") };

        return promise;
    }
}

var test = new Test();
test.postFileAjax(null);
```

Error:

```
(unknown) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a promise
    at CancelablePromise.Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new CancelablePromise (<anonymous>:44:28)
    at __awaiter (<anonymous>:7:12)
    at Test.postFileAjax (<anonymous>:62:16)
    at <anonymous>:75:6
    at HTMLButtonElement.excuteButton.onclick (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/playground.js:242)
```

What am I doing wrong? I see that in ES6 you could subclass the `Promise` (see [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351519/201303)), so I would expect it also in TypeScript.

Using Typescript 2.1 and targeting es5

You can see the same result if you run the code in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20CancelablePromise%3CT%3E%20extends%20Promise%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cancelMethod%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(executor%3A%20(resolve%3A%20(value%3F%3A%20T%20%7C%20PromiseLike%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20reject%3A%20(reason%3F%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(executor)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Set%20the%20prototype%20explicitly.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20See%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoft%2FTypeScript-wiki%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FBreaking-Changes.md%23extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.setPrototypeOf(this%2C%20CancelablePromise.prototype)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fcancel%20the%20operation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cancel()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.cancelMethod)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.cancelMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20async%20postFileAjax%3CT%3E(file%3A%20File)%3A%20CancelablePromise%20%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20promiseFunc%20%3D%20(resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve()%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20promise%20%3D%20new%20CancelablePromise%3CT%3E(promiseFunc)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promise.cancelMethod%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22cancel!%22)%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20promise%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.postFileAjax(null)%3B), click "run" and check the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in the new page.

[image: Error in console]

How do I solve this runtime error?

---

PS: a related error on stackoverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327229/typescript-subclass-extend-of-promise-does-not-refer-to-a-promise-compatible-c), but that a compile error and solved. I have split the compile and runtime error.

Comment: What is the reason for `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CancelablePromise.prototype);`?

Comment: @unional it's from the link (also included in the post) "Recommendation - 

As a recommendation, you can manually adjust the prototype immediately after any super(...) calls."

Comment: You cannot cancel promises.  I think you are thinking of Maybes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified your example; this runs without error:

```
interface CancelablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    cancel: () => void;
}

class Test {
    postFileAjax<T>(file: File): CancelablePromise<T> {
        const promiseFunc = (resolve) => { resolve() };
        const promise = new Promise<T>(promiseFunc);
        const cancel = () => { console.log("cancel!") };
        const cancelablePromise = Object.assign(promise, { cancel });
        return cancelablePromise;
    }
}

const test = new Test();
const testPromise = test.postFileAjax(null);
testPromise.cancel();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20CancelablePromise%3CT%3E%20extends%20Promise%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cancelMethod%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(executor%3A%20(resolve%3A%20(value%3F%3A%20T%20%7C%20PromiseLike%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20reject%3A%20(reason%3F%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(executor)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Set%20the%20prototype%20explicitly.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20See%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoft%2FTypeScript-wiki%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FBreaking-Changes.md%23extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.setPrototypeOf(this%2C%20CancelablePromise.prototype)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fcancel%20the%20operation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20cancel()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.cancelMethod)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.cancelMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20async%20postFileAjax%3CT%3E(file%3A%20File)%3A%20CancelablePromise%20%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20promiseFunc%20%3D%20(resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve()%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20promise%20%3D%20new%20CancelablePromise%3CT%3E(promiseFunc)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promise.cancelMethod%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22cancel!%22)%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20promise%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.postFileAjax(null)%3B)

- I used interface inheritance rather than a new class.
- I copied the `cancel` function right onto `promise`.